# What network topology is best practice for multiple geographical locations?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

What would be the best practice case for networking four different PC located across Bhilai into one network?

Example: We have 4 separate computer stored at the following geographical locations that need to be networked together:

- Supela
- Vaishali Nagar
- Smriti Nagar
- Nehru Nagar

They would require the network to share data stored on each individual computer with each other freely.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the network is small enough and the bandwidth requirement high enough to justify the suggestion to build a fully-meshed network. A dedicated hub-and-spoke would also be fine but would then make it preferable to store all data centrally.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally LAN is used for the short network span of maximum 2km of areas and impractical to exceed more than it, that to share movies, as for some implementation its range is exceeded to the range of cities probably termed as MAN(Metropolitan Are Network). But, MAN is used for an entirely different purpose.

Many home networks use the star topology. A star network features a central connection point called a "hub node" that may be a network hub, switch or router. Star topology is much more reliable than Bus or Ring topology, as a fault in the cable can bring down the whole network. Disadvantage in Star topology is regarding the cable cost as more number of cables are required.

Comment: so u mean star topology is suitable for that...but why not mesh topology??